# Coefficients and Parameters for contracted Gaussian basis sets

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-chemistry, optimization

This is a repost from Chemistry.stackexchange in the hopes that someone here will be able to help me. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

As far as I understand, an STO-NG contracted Gaussian basis function has the following form:

$$\phi_{\mu}^{CGF}(\vec{r}) = \sum_{p=1}^{N} d_{p\mu} (x-X_A)^{i_{p\mu}} (y-Y_A)^{j_{p\mu}} (z-Z_A)^{k_{p\mu}} e^{-\alpha_{p\mu}\zeta^{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{R_{A}}|}$$

where the contraction coefficients, $d_{k\mu}$ and exponents, $\alpha_{k\mu}$ are chosen such that $\phi_{\mu}$ provides the 'best fit' to a Slater-type orbital having stater-exponent $\zeta$, $\vec{R_{A}}=(X_A,Y_A,Z_A)$ is a fixed reference centre (usually a nucleus) and $l_{p\mu} = i_{p\mu} + j_{p\mu} + k_{p\mu}$ defines the angular momentum of the primitive Gaussian function:

$$g_{p\mu} = (x-X_A)^{i_{p\mu}} (y-Y_A)^{j_{p\mu}} (z-Z_A)^{k_{p\mu}} e^{-\alpha_{p\mu}\zeta^{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{R_{A}}|}$$.

I'm having problems interpreting data files documenting contraction coefficients and exponents for various basis sets.

For example, please consider the following snippet from the Gaussian 94 STO-3G basis set file documenting contraction parameters for Carbon:

```
****
C     0 
S   3   1.00
     71.6168370              0.15432897       
     13.0450960              0.53532814       
      3.5305122              0.44463454       
SP   3   1.00
      2.9412494             -0.09996723             0.15591627       
      0.6834831              0.39951283             0.60768372       
      0.2222899              0.70011547             0.39195739       
****
```

I have read in various places that there are enough coefficients here to describe 5 contracted functions, but I see only enough for 3 maximum (if the exponents are the same, but the coefficients change between 2S and 2P). I'd be eternally grateful if someone could explain for me, precisely how one would determine the following information from such a basis set data file:

1) Which EXACT basis functions appear within each contracted function?

2) How many contracted Gaussian basis functions there are?

If possible, would you be able to do the same for the following snippet, again for Carbon, Gaussian 94, but this time for the more complicated 6-31++G** basis set?:

```
****
C     0 
S   6   1.00
   3047.5249000              0.0018347        
    457.3695100              0.0140373        
    103.9486900              0.0688426        
     29.2101550              0.2321844        
      9.2866630              0.4679413        
      3.1639270              0.3623120        
SP   3   1.00
      7.8682724             -0.1193324              0.0689991        
      1.8812885             -0.1608542              0.3164240        
      0.5442493              1.1434564              0.7443083        
SP   1   1.00
      0.1687144              1.0000000              1.0000000        
SP   1   1.00
      0.0438000              1.0000000              1.0000000        
D   1   1.00
      0.8000000              1.0000000        
****
```

Thank-you for reading.